# Listen to Keys while JFrame isn't visible

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener

I'm creating a small person program that I want to run in the background until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

It's a JFrame window and I have `setVisible(false)` when something happens. After it's no longer visible, I need it to listen for the above keys and then display the JFrame again.

I've tried `KeyEventDispatcher` and even [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) and both didn't work.

How do I listen to keys in the background?

Comment: Why did ``KeyEventDispatcher`` and JNativeHook not work?

Comment: A KeyEventDispatcher will never work since Java doesn't have access to the KeyEvents if the window does not have focus.

Comment: If you are trying to listen to the keys while your Java program does not have focus, then I don't believe there is really any good way of doing this in java. Without some sort of plug-in or OS API, your best bet would be C++ or another language that is much closer to the OS level and can possibly link into OS key handlers

Comment: @Haloboy Therefore it is important to know why JNativeHook didn't work

Comment: [Don't repost your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: what OS you running?

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I'm not sure why it didn't work. I basically used their example code and it just didn't do anything. As for reposting it, they are two different questions.

Comment: I'd be use SystemTray with JPopupMenu or by add ActionListener to TrayIcon

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest using a KeyListener.
Here is the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Java can only listen to KeyEvents when the window has focus. If the window did have focus you should use `Key Bindings`, not a KeyListener. (1-).

Comment: A ``KeyListener`` doesn't work ouside a window and the documentation is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html